# isdigit() works independently but not working with np.where

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
    Info
0   Tap
1   15k
2   rot
3   12psi
```

I am running to code below to get only the numerical values into a new column. If the string does not contain numerical values '-' should be in the new column

```
df['num']=np.where(any(char.isdigit() for char in df['Info']),df['Info'], '-')
```

I get all '-`'s !!!

However, when the run `any(char.isdigit() for char in <text to check>` i get true or false correctly.

For example 
`any(char.isdigit() for char in '15k')` returns `True` and

`any(char.isdigit() for char in 'Tap')` returns `False`. These are the same values that are in the dataframe itself!! Any idea why it is not working withing np.where?

Comment: `isdigit()` requires the *entire string* to be digits.  `'15k'.isdigit()` will return `False`.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of numpy. You're trying to use a single true/false value to determine the value of an entire DF column. That's not how it works. `np.where([char.isdigit() for char in df['Info']],df['Info'], '-')` would be closer, but still is going row-by-row, not characters within the row

Comment: Also, `np.where(any...)` is a wrong usage.  You should be having a similar structure to your expected result.

Comment: Tested `print ([char.isdigit() for char in df['Info']])` and return all `False`s correctly

Comment: @Krrr please run the code. I am using a for loop to check each character & using `any()`, it will return `True` for `15k` & false for `Tap`

Comment: @SH-SF `for char in df['Info']` is not doing what you think it's doing.  It's not checking each character of each element.  It's just checking whether the entire element `isdigit()`.

Comment: @jezrael doesn't `np.where` check row by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `isdigit` will only be `True` whenever the string is exclusively composed by numerical characters. Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
l = ['123', 'ab12', 'shf']

list(map(str.isdigit, l))
# [True, False, False]
```

---

> However, when the run any(char.isdigit() for char in  i get true or false correctly

That is because the input iterator for `any` is a string in this case, and hence while iterating over the string it does find numerical values:

```
any(char.isdigit() for char in '123aswd')
# True
```

But as shown in the initial example, when the input iterator is a list of strings, unless they are composed only by numerical characters `str.isdigit` will return `False`.

---

Instead you could do something like:

```
df['num'] = df.Info.str.extract(r'(\d+)').fillna('-')
```

---

```
print(df)

    Info num
0    Tap   -
1    15k  15
2    rot   -
3  12psi  12
```

Comment: I got this part already. Thanks. I was trying to find why `isdigit()` is not working with `np.where`

Comment: Yes, added a brief explanation in the beginning on why its not working as expected @SH-SF

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there are two main issues:

1. Your `isdigit()` will return `False` unless the entire string is digit.
2. The `np.where` should have the same structure you are trying to pass back into your `df`.  In your case you are only passing one single boolean value.

Try this:

```
df['num'] = np.where(df['Info'].str.contains('\d'), df['Info'], '-')
```

Output:

```
    Info    num
0    Tap      -
1    15k    15k
2    rot      -
3  12psi  12psi
```

This is assuming you want the entire element copied over.  If you only want the digits themselves, use the `str.extract` method in yatu's answer.

Comment: Thanks for show how to make this work with `np.where` :-)